# How can I disable compiler warnings regarding certain library?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-warnings, clion

I'm using CLion as my IDE. I downloaded MinGW from [here](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) (comes with boost), extracted, installed and connected it to CLion successfully. Then I set my compiler flags in `CMakeLists` and when I compiled my program, I encounted hundreds of warnings coming from boost libraries (in this case - `boost/lexical_cast.hpp`).

I really want to use most, if not all, of these compiler flags, but I also don't want boost (which is for sure better written than any of my own programs) to generate that much noise.

Is there any way of disabling all warnings from particular header / library (maybe even `namespace`)?

Comment: There is **no such thing** in modern C++ as "from a library". Modern C++ code is template intensive.

Comment: I used that term to indicate the intention. While your comment is technically correct, I believe the wider context could bring some interesting answers. Forwarding couple of years, I could as well listed a module there

Comment: Correct support of real modules is badly wanted in C++. But without clean templates with true concepts, you can't have true modules with well defined boundaries. Templates are a mess, all of C++ is a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the include paths as `SYSTEM` instead of standard ones:

```
target_include_directories(target SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

This only works for GCC and clang, as Visual Studio doesn't have a specific include flag for system paths.

Comment: Unforunately, this gives me the following CMake error: `(target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "SYSTEM" which is not built
  by this project.`. To successfully include `boost` for now, I've been using: `include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})`

Comment: `target` is the name of the target you want to add Boost include path to. The error is self explanatory.

Comment: My bad, works beautifully. Thank you! Will accept the answer as soon as I am able to

Comment: No worries ;) happy to help.

Comment: For me this still required a INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE tag immediately following the SYSTEM tag to work, i.e.
`target_include_directories(target SYSTEM PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})`